# How do I go to a cell (found with index match) to change the value?

Tags: vba, excel

I have made some 'change' buttons that need to go to the cell which has been found with Index as shown down here.

```
Private Sub CommandButton16_Click()

    Dim behandel As Variant

    behandel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("bestand totaal").Range("E2:E996"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Gegevens").Range("B3"), Sheets("Bestand totaal").Range("J2:J996"), 0), 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Shai Rado you can see it here

Comment: @ShaiRado here it is

Comment: you got a good answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can make 'behandel' a range and then use Set to get the reference of the formula to that range. Then you can simply select that cell:

```
Dim behandel As Range

Set behandel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("bestand totaal").Range("E2:E996"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Gegevens").Range("B3"), Sheets("Bestand totaal").Range("J2:J996"), 0), 1)
behandel.Select
```